# Build multiple piecewise function in a for loop python

Tags: python, piecewise

I was trying to build multiple piecewise functions in python by using for loop. Here is a simple example:

```
a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
weight = {} 
for i in range(2): 
 a_a = a[i][0]
 a_b = a[i][1]
 name = str(i)
 print(a_a,a_b)
 def piece_wise_function(t):
     if t < 0: 
         return a_a 
     else: 
         return a_b 
 weight[name] = piece_wise_function
 print(weight[name](-1))
 print(weight[name](1))
```

Here are the results:

```
1 2
1
2
3 4
3
4
```

Look good so far and it is what I want, where the first piecewise function generates `1` when facing a negative value and `2` for a positive value and the second piecewise function generate `3` for a negative value and `4` for a positive value . However, when I use the piecewise functions,

```
print(weight['1'](-1))
print(weight['0'](-1))
print(weight['1'](1))
print(weight['0'](1))
```

The results are

```
3
3
4
4
```

Just wondering why `print(weight['0'](-1))` is `3` instead of `1` that I am supposed to have and why `print(weight['0'](1))` is `4` instead of `2`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You're close, except that your code fails to run, due to the undefined list.  Since you have multiple `print` statements, you should label them for easy reading.  Why do you repeatedly redefine your function?

Comment: @Prune, thanks for your comments, I have edited the questions. Please let me know if you have any question. The reason why I repeatedly redefine the function is that I target to have multiple piecewise functions with different settings.

Comment: `weight[name] = piece_wise_function`  This does not include an argument. I think the function requires you to pass one argument.

Comment: @ Joe Ferndz, thanks for your comments. I was trying to not include any argument except ```t```. Other part of my simulation code only use ```piece_wise_function(t)```, so here in the simple example, I did not include other argument than ```t```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
weight = {} 

for i in range(2): 
    a_a = a[i][0]
    a_b = a[i][1]
    name = str(i)


    #define a function that returns a function passing a_a and a_b as params
    def piece_wise_function(a_a, a_b):

        #when this function returns its scope will be isolated - notice this is where we are passing in t
        def anonymous( t ):
            #use nonlocal keyword if you need to edit a_a or a_b - if just reading I think you don't need
            nonlocal a_a 
            nonlocal a_b
            if t < 0: 
                return a_a 
            else: 
                return a_b 
        return anonymous
    
    #now call piece wise function which returns anonymous with isolated scope
    weight[name] = piece_wise_function(a_a, a_b) 


print(weight['0'](-1))
print(weight['0'](1))
print(weight['1'](-1))
print(weight['1'](1))

#output
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, after for loop last known `a_a` value is `3` and last known `a_b` value `4`.
That's why you are seeing `3` instead of `1` and `4` instead of `2`.

For example if you change your `a` array value from `a = [(1,2),(3,4)]` to `a = [(3,4),(1,2)]` your output will for `print(weight['1']((-1)))` will be `1`, because last known `a_a` value will be `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate it. Hmmm... OK, got your point. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A few things are happening in your code. Let's break the code down a bit.

You have a for loop iterating twice: `range (2)` which equates to `0` and `1`.

The loop iterates through twice and assigns values to dictionary `weight`. The values assigned are:

```
weight['0'](0) = 1
weight['0'](1) = 2
weight['1'](0) = 3
weight['1'](1) = 4
```

At this time, the value of `a_a` is `3` and `a_b` is `4`.

When you try to print the value again, the way you defined the function assignment to the dictionary value, it takes the argument and resets the value in the dictionary.

So when your new code executes:

```
print(weight['1'](-1))
print(weight['0'](-1))
print(weight['1'](1))
print(weight['0'](1))
```

It goes to the function definition and reassigns the value of 3 and 4 back to the dictionary keys. That's why you get 3 and 4 printed.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your clear answer. Yes, I was trying to have two piecewise functions, so I use for loop. I thought the values of 1 and 2 would be fixed for the first piecewise function and 3 and 4 would be for the second piecewise function, and there would not further reassign any values when using these piecewise functions. But, you are right. Thank you.